# Pipes behind Vent Grates - Safe to Remove?

Tags: heating, pipe

In the bedrooms of a home we just purchased, there are vertical pipes behind vent grates (see picture). Each bedroom has an upper and lower grate, both with visible pipes behind them.

The pipe is about 2" diameter.

I'm thinking these pipes are part of an older heating system, but thought it was weird that they're only in the 2 bedrooms and no other rooms in the house.

House previously had oil heating (not sure on the specifics), and has been upgraded to natural gas forced air (utilizing other ceiling vents).

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know what these pipes might be?
2. Would they be safe to remove? (pondering opening the channel and creating a built-in book case).

[image: Pipes]

Thanks!

Comment: It would not be wise to remove these pipes without knowing exactly what is their function and what are the possible effects of removing them.  Are they light, thin metal (as for a vent) or are they dense, heavy metal? Is a magnet attracted to them?

Comment: I was wondering if the Pipe could be a gas vent? I agree with Jim Stewart you should know what they are used for before trying to remove them.

Comment: "Horizontal" pipes? Is the picture rotated 90 degrees, and if so which way is "up"?

Comment: Interesting! Could be. All gas operations are on the other side of the house, but still possible. I'll check the attic for pipe direction.

Comment: Whoops! @DanielGriscom - that should be vertical. I'll update.